# Difference between consecutive rows in C++

Tags: c++

I have a file of automatic weather station (AWS) data.

I want to compute the differences among data for consecutive timestamps and make new file of it.

The original information looks like this

[image: Original data]

I want to make new file with the value like this. Only the first row contains the original value, and the rest will be the difference.

[image: Difference data]

Could anyone help me with this? thank you.

p.s: I'm using visual studio code and c++ language

Comment: How exactly do you want to achieve the compression? Why is an out-of-the-box solution like zip insufficient?

Comment: I just want to make a new file that only contains the difference value of the original data. 
I've done several simulations to compress data with compression algorithm, such as using the huffman algorithm, arithmetic code, etc.
But at this matter I want to know if compute the differences among data for consecutive timestamps can also give me better result before compress it with compression algorithm.

Comment: p.s: I just edited the post so it does not make any misperception.

Comment: The parts of this algorithm have been covered ad nauseam on this site and others, but I totally understand how something like this can appear overwhelming. The general process would be to. `read the first line`, `parse the first line`, `save the values of interest`, `write the first line to a new file`,  `read the next line`, `parse this line`, `save the values of interest`, `calculate your outputs for this line`, `write this line to your new file`, `read the next line...`. If you don't know how to do any one of those things, search for the solution. I promise you'll find it.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? If you are new to C++ and don't know how to read and write files, read some [appropriate base tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/). Other than that, the usual base approach would be to write a class for each entry, a class for all entries, appropriate constructors and parsers and a routine to make your transformation.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend encapsulating the record in a structure:

```
struct Record
{
    std::string date;
    std::string time;
    double      chill;
    double      dewin;
    double      dew;
    double      heatin;
    double      heat;
    double      thw;
    double      humin;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    input >> r.date;
    input >> r.time;
    input >> r.chill;
    input >> r.dewin;
    input >> r.dew;
    input >> r.heatin;
    input >> r.heat;
    input >> r.thw;
    input >> r.humin;
    return input;
}
```

You can also add a "diff" method:

```
struct Record
{
  //...
  Record diff(const Record& r) const; // Return "r" - "this".
};

Record Record::diff(const Record& r) const
{
  Record result;
  result.date = r.date;
  result.time = r.time;
  result.chill = r.chill - chill;
  result.dewin = r.dewin - dewin;
  //...
  return result;
}
```

Your main code could look like this:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record present;
Record previous;
Record difference;
input_file >> previous;
Output_Record(previous);
database.push_back(previous);
while (input_file >> present)
{
    database.push_back(present);
    difference = present.diff(previous);
    Output_Record(difference);
    previous = present;
}
```

The function `Output_Record` writes a `Record` instance to your output file.

Answer (score 1):

This is some simple demo code, it will vary depending on the type of file from which you are reading your data. I am using `tsv` files for simplicity.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("data.tsv");
    std::ofstream fout("compressed.tsv");
    double chill1, dewin1, dew1, heatin1, heat1, thw1, humin1, chill2, dewin2, dew2, heatin2, heat2, thw2, humin2;
    std::string date, time;
    if (fin >> date >> time >> chill1 >> dewin1 >> dew1 >> heatin1 >> heat1 >> thw1 >> humin1)
        fout << date << ' ' << time << '\t' << chill1 << '\t' << dewin1 << '\t' <<dew1 << '\t' << heatin1 << '\t' << heat1 << '\t' << thw1 << '\t' << humin1 << '\n';
    while (fin >> date >> time >> chill2 >> dewin2 >> dew2 >> heatin2 >> heat2 >> thw2 >> humin2)
        fout << date << ' ' << time << '\t' << chill2 - chill1 << '\t' << dewin2 - dewin1 << '\t' << dew2 - dew1 << '\t' << heatin2 - heatin1 << '\t' << heat2 - heat1 << '\t' << thw2 - thw1 << '\t' << humin2 - humin1 << '\n';
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    // system("cat compressed.tsv");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample content inside `data.tsv` file:

```
01/01/2018 00:10    21.6    13.7    13.7    11.9    9.5     21.6    13.7
01/01/2018 00:20    21.8    13.8    13.8    12.1    10.2    21.8    13.8   
01/01/2018 00:40    22.2    13.7    13.7    12.1    10.1    22.2    13.7
01/01/2018 00:50    22.3    13.7    13.7    12.3    10.3    22.3    13.7
01/01/2018 01:00    22.4    13.7    13.7    12.4    10.3    22.4    13.7
```

Result on [test run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wIjrv78jmzaKYqkv):

```
01/01/2018 00:10    21.6    13.7    13.7    11.9    9.5     21.6    13.7
01/01/2018 00:20    0.2     0.1     0.1     0.2     0.7     0.2     0.1
01/01/2018 00:40    0.6     0       0       0.2     0.6     0.6     0
01/01/2018 00:50    0.7     0       0       0.4     0.8     0.7     0
01/01/2018 01:00    0.8     0       0       0.5     0.8     0.8     0
```

**[EDIT]**

Here is the extended code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Record {
    static const char delim = '\t'; // ',' for .csv files and '\t' for .tsv files
    std::string       date;
    std::string       time;
    double            chill;
    double            dewIn;
    double            dew;
    double            heatIn;
    double            heat;
    double            thw;
    double            humIn;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Record &);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Record &);
    Record operator-(const Record &);
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Record &r) {
    char discard;
    input >> r.date >> r.time;
    input.get(discard);
    input >> r.chill;
    input.get(discard);
    input >> r.dewIn;
    input.get(discard);
    input >> r.dew;
    input.get(discard);
    input >> r.heatIn;
    input.get(discard);
    input >> r.heat;
    input.get(discard);
    input >> r.thw;
    input.get(discard);
    input >> r.humIn;
    return input;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Record &r) {
    output << r.date << ' ' << r.time << r.delim
           << r.chill << r.delim
           << r.dewIn << r.delim
           << r.dew << r.delim
           << r.heatIn << r.delim
           << r.heat << r.delim
           << r.thw << r.delim
           << r.humIn << '\n';
    return output;
}

Record Record::operator-(const Record &r) {
    Record diff;
    diff.date = date;
    diff.time = time;
    diff.chill = chill - r.chill;
    diff.dewIn = dewIn - r.dewIn;
    diff.dew = dew - r.dew;
    diff.heatIn = heatIn - r.heatIn;
    diff.heat = heat - r.heat;
    diff.thw = thw - r.thw;
    diff.humIn = humIn - r.humIn;
    return diff;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("original.tsv");
    std::ofstream output("compressed.tsv");
    Record first, current;
    if (input >> first) {
        output << first;
        while (input >> current)
            output << current - first;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**PS:** There is a certain doubt if you want the difference between the first and some other entry or difference between adjacent entries. My code is the one which gives the output as shown in your question (i.e. between the first and some other entry). You need to change the `main` function as follows if you want difference between adjacent timestampes:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::ifstream input("original.tsv");
    std::ofstream output("compressed.tsv");
    Record prev, curr;
    if (input >> curr) {
        output << curr; // first
        prev = curr;
        while (input >> curr) {
            output << curr - prev;
            prev = curr;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output as:

```
01/01/2018 00:10    21.6    13.7    13.7    11.9    9.5     21.6    13.7
01/01/2018 00:20    0.2     0.1     0.1     0.2     0.7     0.2     0.1
01/01/2018 00:40    0.4     -0.1    -0.1    0       -0.1    0.4     -0.1
01/01/2018 00:50    0.1     0       0       0.2     0.2     0.1     0
01/01/2018 01:00    0.1     0       0       0.1     0       0.1     0
```